# Sorting a list based on associated scores

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am looking for some help in creating a cluster of items in a list based on
association scores. To explain it please see below the dictionary object and the desired list that I am looking to generate;

Defintion of the `dict` object:

```
strScoresDict[uniqueID] = (itemElement1, itemElement2, associatedScore)
```

Example:

```
('item1', 'item2', 100)

('item1', 'item3', 40)

('item1', 'item4', 80)

('item2', 'item3', 40)

('item2', 'item4', 100)

('item3', 'item4', 20)
```

sorted list;

```
('item1', 'item2', 'item4', 'item3')
```

My target list can have more than 1000 entries

The association score is generated based on business-specific logic and the range of score is fixed between `0` and `100`.

Comment: You should improve the description of your problem, what exactly(example) are you expecting to get.

Comment: I'm not sure about your rule to sort the dictionary clearly.

Comment: The output I am looking for needs to check the weight of the association score and cluster the items with the highest scores together. 
As shown in the illustration above e.g., item1 and item2 are close associated hence item2 follows item1, but item2 and item3 have a lowers association score compared item2 and item4, hence the sequence needs to push out item3 below item4. 
Hope this helps in clarifying the output I am looking for.

Comment: @ipyinwild You need a transitive relation to be able to sort at all, and it isn't clear to me that your relation is transitive. Are you really trying to sort, and not cluster? Why does `item1` come first? Do you think that the algorithm is deterministic?

Comment: Hi Giles, you are right I am trying to create clusters. item1 is the first item cluster followed by the next one. The algorithm should ignore items that have already been included in a cluster as it is progressing through the scores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict # using defaultdict makes the sums easier

correlations = defaultdict(int) # default to int (i.e. 0)

for i1, i2, correl in strScoresDict: # loop through data
    correlations[i1] += correl # add score for first item
    correlations[i2] += correl # and second item

output = sorted(correlations, 
                key=lambda x: correlations[x], 
                reverse=True) # sort keys by value
```

Note, however, that the output is

```
output == ['item2', 'item1', 'item4', 'item3']
```

As the total correlations are

```
{'item1': 220, 'item3': 100, 'item2': 240, 'item4': 200}
```

You can [read about `defaultdict` here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).